# Java arrays - Of what class are arrays of the form "int[] intArray = new int[4];" an instance?

Tags: java, arrays

Clearly these are a class, right? But I can't find any javadoc api's on them. I can find an Arrays class which offers methods to work with these types of arrays, but not an actual class for these. I've always been confused about this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are an instance of `int[].class`

```
new int[]{1,2,3,4} instanceof int[]; // true
```

Comment: Which basically provides `length`, the basic `Object` methods, and nothing else.

Comment: You might add that the JVM synthesizes these classes at runtime, on demand.

Answer (score 0):

From [Java Language Specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/arrays.doc.html)

In the Java programming language arrays are objects (§4.3.1), are dynamically created, and may be **assigned to variables of type Object** (§4.3.2). **All methods of class Object may be invoked on an array**.

Answer (score 0):

"new int[4]" is an instance of the class called [I which is the class of one dimensional integer array. Every one dimensional integer array is an instance of this class

new int[x][y] is an instance of the class called [[I. 
new int[x][y][z] is an instance of the class called [[[I.

Notice the pattern here?

Under the hood JMV has a metaclass from which array types like [I, [[I or [[[I are instanced at the time of need. Same logic applies to the all primitive types.